# How to debug a 3rd-party Python package in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to enter into imported package while debugging in VS code

As an example:

```
import os
import mdfreader
k123 = mdfreader.mdf("Test.mf4")
```

How to enter into the mdf function  in the imported package

Answer (score 34):

In your `launch.json` add the [`"justMyCode": false` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugoptions). That will allow you to step into third-party code.

Comment: It looks like this option was renamed to `"justMyCode": false`  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2087#issuecomment-434372548

Answer (score 3):

@Brett's answer is correct. However, when trying to debug 3rd party package **while running unit tests** (as opposed to running a predefined *launch configuration*) you need to create a separate configuration entry in the `launch.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Debug Unit Test",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "test",
  "justMyCode": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends to the IDE you are using! For example in PyCharm IDE by pressing **Ctrl+B** you can simply reach to the function you are calling.

Comment: Thank you Ssein i will try pycharm

Comment: Ok! Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use `Alt` and left mouse and click the function you want to explore.
And you can edit it in `keybindings.json` by `Ctrl+K` `Ctrl+S`.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging generaly you can `step into` to inspect the inner function/code.

Comment: This would be more helpful if you provided an example or linked to a tutorial or something. For example, I'm trying to debug a 3rd party module to see why it is breaking for my use case, and I need to see how values get passed around in the package to see if what I provide at the highest level ever makes it to the function imported from a utilities file into the main module.

Answer (score 0):

@Tomasz's answer still works, though the editor would warn you that *"test" is not an allowed value for the "request" property of launch configs configurations*.

According to the discussion in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15790 and the document in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests, I think now the recommended way to debug 3rd-party python package when running tests is:

```json
{
  "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${file}",
  "purpose": ["debug-test"],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "justMyCode": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

two lines should be set in project settings.

"justMyCode": false,
"purpose":["debug-in-terminal"]

```
eg. launch.json:
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "purpose":["debug-in-terminal"],
    "justMyCode": false,
    "args": ["-arg1", "-arg1"],
    "env": {"env1": "val1", "env2": "val2"}
  }
]
```